# How to define custom size on Google Map when using closures in event listeners

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I' am using Google Map to plot the marker and a small popup box that will appear when someone clicks on the market. Image is attached. By Default, Google has set fixed width of the Popup and I wanted to change its size. I was not able to anything on [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure).

**Below are my codes**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-14.306407, -170.695018),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            var voyagePlanCoordinates = [               
      new google.maps.LatLng(),
    ];

    var voyagePath<?php echo $voyage_id; ?> = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: voyagePlanCoordinates,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: "",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 5
    });
    voyagePath.setMap(map);
    setMarkers(map, voyages);
  }

    var voyages = [];

    function setMarkers(map, locations) {
      var image = {
        url: '/wp-content/themes/theme/resources/images/marker.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
      };
      for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var voyage = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(voyage[1], voyage[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: voyage[0],
            zIndex: voyage[3]
        });
                voyage_msg(marker, i);
      }
    }
            function voyage_msg(marker, num){

                var message = [];
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: message[num]
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
        });
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
```

Please Help!

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, **Complete**, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That is the minimal code and straight to point. Most the things such as PHP Codes has been stripped.

Comment: The API doesn't set a fixed size. The size depends on the content of the InfoWindow and the size of the map. Use CSS to force a custom size(but note that the API always tries to create a InfoWindow that fits into the map-viewport).

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  It includes PHP that isn't resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any extra code or api call to set the width of the popover. All you need is basic CSS

```
 .map-closures{
      width: 200px;
    }
```

That should do the trick.